# 'worksheet.activate' seems to have stopped working

Tags: excel, vba

Have client personal data put onto monthly worksheets under the 'activate' command when they are opened. Have been using this for countless years without any problem ...but, just recently they have taken a funny turn and no longer work as expected with some files still ok, others keeping old data after attempts to change. I've tried copying working code and replaced but problem still ongoing
sample code

```
Private Sub worksheet_activate()
Dim filename As String
Dim Row As Variant
Dim Column As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Me.ScrollArea = "A16:y56"
      
'description
    Worksheets("april").Range("c4").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("prsnldet").Range("g28")
 'title
    Worksheets("april").Range("g5").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("prsnldet").Range("g26")
'other titles as per client detail
```

Have read several posts regarding the 'activate / select' opinions
Any suggestions would be most welcome

Comment: Are `Worksheets("april")` and the sheet containing the `Private Sub worksheet_activate()` procedure the same? If not, you have to activate a worksheet before selecting anything on it: `Worksheets("april").Activate`. And anyway, you need not select a cell to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear exactly where your problem is, unless you have other event handlers which are turning off `EnableEvents` and then not resetting it.

```vb
Private Sub worksheet_activate()

    Dim filename As String
    Dim Row As Variant
    Dim Column As Variant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Me.ScrollArea = "A16:y56"
          
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("prsnldet")
        Me.Range("c4").Value = .Range("g28").Value 'description
        Me.Range("g5").Value = .Range("g26").Value 'title
        'other titles as per client detail
    End With
```

Comment: Heard there was a known problem with ACTIVATE / SELECT and thought this was my 'meeting' it...have been using same macro on all client workbooks for donkeys years...until recently no problems...had MS 365 'update' a few months back that caused disaster and thought this was another...everything now working in keeping with your valued solution...thank you so much